# How to make the div position in the middle column on small devices to make this invoice head responsive

Tags: css

Below 767 with I want that the middle columns date, due date and id should stack up one below the other(due date, date, then id or date, due date, and id where due date and id below the date column which is at the middle) which means there should be 3 columns as opposed to five on width above 767.
How to make this happen using css. If there something even better to make this responsive then please share.

Should i create a separate row for mobile and hide it on larger devices.
Or is is possible to work with the same row and make the middle three divs stack one after the other.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 .container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .invo-to,.due,.date,.id {
  float: left;
 }
 .invo-from {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
 }
 .invo-to {
  width: 25%;
 }
 .due,.date,.id {
  width: 16%;
 }
 .invo-from {
  width: 25%;
 }
 h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
 }
 p {
  font-size: 16px;
 }
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="invo-to">
 <h6>Invoice To</h6>
 <p>John Mason</p>
 <p>john@gmail.com</p>
</div>
<div class="due">
 <h6>Due Date</h6>
 <p>11-05-1990</p>
</div>
<div class="date">
 <h6>Date</h6>
 <p>11-05-1990</p>
</div>
<div class="id">
 <h6>Invoice Id</h6>
 <p>66</p>
</div>
<div class="invo-from">
 <h6>Invoice From</h6>
 <p>Xskd Lksdds di LTD</p>
 <p>lksdds@gmail.com</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use media queries to specify properties of your page for all screen sizes and make your website responsive check this link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .details {
        display: flex;
    }
    .invo-to {
        width: 15%;
    }
    .invo-from {
        width: 20%;
    }
    .due_date_id {
        width: 65%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    h6 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container {
        width:100%;
    }
    .due_date_id {
        width: 33%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .invo-to {
        width: 33%;
    }
    .invo-from {
        width: 33%;
    }
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="details">
        <div class="invo-to">
            <h6>Invoice To</h6>
            <p>John Mason</p>
            <p>john@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="due_date_id">
            <div class="due">
                <h6>Due Date</h6>
                <p>11-05-1990</p>
            </div>
            <div class="date">
                <h6>Date</h6>
                <p>11-05-1990</p>
            </div>
            <div class="id">
                <h6>Invoice Id</h6>
                <p>66</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="invo-from">
            <h6>Invoice From</h6>
            <p>Xskd Lksdds di LTD</p>
            <p>lksdds@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a responsive web page, it's better to use bootstrap, it's much easier and faster way, but if you can't learn bootstrap for the moment, you can use flexbox and media queries.

1. Flexbox enables you to create responsive layout without using float
   property, it is recommanded to learn it because it's very powerfull, in this case you will need 2 properties, `display:flex;` to enable flexbox and `flex-direction:row` or `flex-direction: column;` to set the direction of blocks inside flexbox https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp
2. Media queries to define css properties in certain conditions, it can be used for different type of screens, this tool is  very usefull to create responsive websites, to enable it you will need `@media condition` where condition can be the width of your screen, or the type of the screen ... https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

The following code will explain it better:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 .container {
  width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
 }

 .invo-from {
  padding-right:15px;
  text-align: right;
     width: 30%;
 }
 .invo-to {
  width: 30%;
    padding-left:15px;
 }
 .due,.date,.id {
  width: 100%;
    
 }
 
 h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
 }
 p {
  font-size: 16px;
 }
  .stacked{
    width: 50%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .stacked{
    width: 40%;
     text-align:center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="invo-to">
 <h6>Invoice To</h6>
 <p>John Mason</p>
 <p>john@gmail.com</p>
</div>
<div class="stacked">
<div class="due">
 <h6>Due Date</h6>
 <p>11-05-1990</p>
</div>
<div class="date">
 <h6>Date</h6>
 <p>11-05-1990</p>
</div>
<div class="id">
 <h6>Invoice Id</h6>
 <p>66</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="invo-from">
 <h6>Invoice From</h6>
 <p>Xskd Lksdds di LTD</p>
 <p>lksdds@gmail.com</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```